# timeout exception in Xamarin.Forms System.Net.WebException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display login message in Xamarin app by calling api ... but it shows

Unhandled Exception:

> System.Net.WebException: 
>   occurred

at this line line

```
var response =await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:40987/Api/Home/Post?username="+username.Text+"&password="+password.Text);
```

I have tried all the suggestions but not getting out of this

```
    private async void Button_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = new User
        {
            UserName = username.Text,
            Password = password.Text

        };


        var Json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(Json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/Json");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //httpClient.GetAsync("windows.digitalgramsoft.com/Api/Home");
        //DisplayAlert("Added", "Your Data has been added", "OK")
        var response =await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:40987/Api/Home/Post?username="+username.Text+"&password="+password.Text);


        var login = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(response);

    }
```

just want to show login message or error message using api

Comment: As suggested in the answer section please add a try catch for the code block for more details, but from the code all i can guess is the the device or the emulator is unable to connect to the endpoint, if you're having a UWP version of the app please try running it. I would suggest adding ip adress and the disabling the firewall atleast to test the endpoint if this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    try{
     var Json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(Json);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/Json");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            //httpClient.GetAsync("windows.digitalgramsoft.com/Api/Home");
            //DisplayAlert("Added", "Your Data has been added", "OK")
            var response =await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:40987/Api/Home/Post?username="+username.Text+"&password="+password.Text);


            var login = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(response);
    }catch(Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Then use a breakpoint to check whats inside the `Exception` object. From there, you can track the source.